# Convert time in float format to time format

Tags: qgis, datetime

I have a shapefile line layer with an attribute for time in float format.

This is what 23.21 and 55 seconds looks like:

```
232155.17
```

This is 03.27 and 01 seconds:

```
32701.64
```

I would like to convert this to a proper time format in Field Calculator.

Comment: What data type for the new field?

Comment: I think Time would be best?

Comment: Lines Shapefile

Comment: As far as I know there is no time data type in shapefiles. Maybe text/string will be best

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
to_time( to_string( "<float_time_field>" ), 'hmmss.z' )
```

---

Since *Shapefiles* do not support `time` data types (there is `date`, but that cannot work without a date...), an easy fix for the above would be to write a **string** representation of your time:

```
format_date( to_time( to_string( "<float_time_field>" ), 'hmmss.z' ), 'hh:mm:ss:z' )
```

Remove `:z` to not include milliseconds.

While you could achieve the same results with plain *regexp* logic, using the `time` detour is somewhat more convenient.

Comment: Hmm; not working, I'm trying this: to_time( to_string( "HMMSS" ), 'hmmss.z' )

Comment: @Bacon_Sammich Yeah, as @BERA said, *Shapefiles* do not support `time`. See my update. You can also wait for someone to add a *regexp* based solution; I doubt there is much to gain from avoiding the `time` detour in favor for *regexp* in the expression, though.

Comment: I got really close with this: 

try (format_date( to_time( to_string( "Time_Float" ), 'hhmmss.z' ), 'hh:mm' ), (format_date( to_time( to_string( "Time_Float" ), 'hmmss.z' ), 'hh:mm' )))

But there are still some values that don't compute, like '1157.85'.

Comment: Well, TBH, that's probably the end of it; without _any_ fixed rules to the float representation, you can't make sense of them. I.e. what does 1157.85 mean? 01:01:57? Or 01:15:07? Or 00:11:57 even?

Comment: When you put it like that... you have an excellent point! Time to go back to the drawing board, thanks for all your help.